# Native app: android delete camera captured image through my app

Tags: android

In my android app i have used camera intent for capture photo.
Once photo taken, on Activity result i got image bitmap data.
I stored the image data in my local db(sqlite db) for further view and send it to server.
But the photo image is available in phone and it displayed in gallery.
I have to delete the photo in phone through app.
How to delete? Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

- Retrieve absolute path to the image file and create `File` object
- Ensure you have write access to it
- Call `File.delete()`

Check for exception and return values

Answer (score 0):

If you used `EXTRA_OUTPUT` on your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`, you (usually) have control over where the image is written, and you can delete it yourself.

If you did not use `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, then the camera app should not be saving a full image anywhere. If it is doing that, it's a bug in that app. However, you do not have any idea where that image lives, and therefore there is nothing that you can do about it.