# Delete discarded images captured from camera in my Android device file manager

Tags: android, camera

I am using camera for saving my captured images to a folder in android but what happens is when I clicked an image but discard it after clicking,,it also gets saved to my image folder on my device.I do not know how to delete it.

here is my part of code:

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // /Log.d("sfas", path);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CROP_IMAGE
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            path = data.getStringExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH);
            Log.d("sfas", path);


            shared.AddSharedValues(LORREY_PATH, path);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {

        shared.AddSharedValues(LORREY_PATH, "");   //this clears the path of the file in LORREY_PATH shared preferences value

        Log.d("else Path", resultCode + "");

        // upload.setImageResource(R.drawable.about_icon_img);
    }
    finish();
```

Comment: Have you tried <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224744/native-app-android-delete-camera-captured-image-through-my-app>?

Comment: It gives null pointer as my file path gets null in else part

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions (I have made [this edit before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41477431/472495), so downvoting this time).

Answer (score 0):

Have you given permission to read the external storage in manifest.?

Comment: When did this variable  LORREY_PATH gets initialised.?

Comment: Which part is throwing the NullPointerException.?

Comment: It gets initialised globally

Comment: If I use File.delete and give its path to it,,,then the path is giving null pointer

Comment: Yes Sreyas ,,It has been